# Why doesn't this loop work when an odd number is entered?

Tags: c, for-loop, fibonacci

The loop in the following code does not work when an odd number is entered in the number of terms.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

//fibonacci series with details...

int main() {

  int n, ter;
  int x1 = 1, x2, x3, x4;

  printf("Enter the number of terms:");
  scanf("%d", & ter);
  for (n = 0; n <= --ter; n++) {

    x1 += x2;
    x2 += x1;
    x3 = x1 + x2;
    printf("%d+%d=%d\n", x1, x2, x3);
    x4 = x2 + x3;

    printf("%d+%d=%d\n", x2, x3, x4);

  }

  printf("\nThx for trying :)");

  return 0;
}
```

When I write 3 for term number it writes 4 term. How can I fix that?

Comment: "loop doesn't work" -- Could you please be more specific? What do you expect? What do you see?

Comment: Please fix your indentaion. Also, a picture of the code you have already provided as text is not needed.

Comment: What happens if you delete the `=--`?

Comment: As the comment by @MOehm illustrates, if you do not get the formatting of your post right, then people miss relevant information. For future posts, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The problem is, no matter how many terms you input, following the logic you create the code, it will always output an `even number` of terms. It is because, each loop, the `for` loop is going to print two terms.

Comment: Take a piece of paper draw the execution for fibonacci for odd numbers using your logic. if the logic is fine  use gdb to debug.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(n=0;n<=--ter;n++){
```

This looks *very* suspect. The fact that you are both increasing the current term number *and* decreasing the termination point would normally mean that you are approaching your end condition twice as fast as you ought to. Think about what happens when you want the eighth term: `n` starts at zero and `ter` at eight, and these are the loops:

```
n    ter    loop#
0    8      1
1    7      2
2    6      3
3    5      4
4    4      5
```

By my count, that's not even *close* to the requested eight iterations. But the reason why this *isn't* a problem for your even counts is the way you actually do your calculations:

```
x1 += x2;
x2 += x1;
x3 = x1 + x2;
```

If you examine what this generates from a starting point of `1, 1`, you can see it actually advances `x1` and `x2` by *two* steps per iteration rather than one, so half the number of iterations is okay. In other words, it would go:

```
 1,  1
 2,  3
 5,  8
13, 21 ...
```

rather than:

```
 1, 1
 1, 2
 2, 3
 3, 5
 5, 8 ...
```

However, this only works for an *even* number of terms because even numbers divide by two, well, evenly :-) If you have an *odd* number, the actual stepping through the values will seem to be one more than is necessary because the final iteration will still do two steps even though only one is desired.

The more usual method (one that isn't affected by odd counts) is to do *one* step at a time, such as with:

```
int x1 = 0, x2 = 1, x3 = 1; // or "1, 1, 2" depending on what
                            // you consider first term.

for (int n = 1; n < ter; n++) {
    printf ("%d + %d = %d\n", x1, x2, x3);
    x1 = x2;  // simply "shift" the values left ONE spot.
    x2 = x3;
    x3 = x1 + x2;
}
printf ("Requested term is %d\n", x1);
```

That's obviously more loops than necessary but the alternative is that you have to stop the loop whenever there's less than two steps left, and detect the need after the loop to do that final single step (no for even counts, yes for odd).

That, in my opinion, needlessly complicates things so I'd suggest just using the one step per iteration approach, especially since there won't be that many steps before your numbers get too big to handle anyway (assuming non-bignum data types).

---

As an aside, another problem is that you don't actually initialise `x2` before using it. That may well work but it's purely by accident and not something you should rely on.